# C++ and boost::python

Tags: c++, python, boost, python-embedding

Can I embed python into my app using only boost:python? Will I need any additional libraries to bring with my app?

Or is there any embeddable language which natively supports unicode chars and does not need any libraries to bring with app

Comment: You always need at least one library: The one implementing the language.

Comment: So, boost:python is just a wrapper on library?

Comment: Well, `boost::python` is a library. I don't actually know a lot about its it, I figure you still have to link to CPython in library form. But my point is, to embed a language you must bring in C++ code (or code callable from C++) which implements the language. By linking it in, statically or dynamically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To integrate Python in a C++ application you can use [Boost.Python](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_51_0/libs/python/doc/) but you can also interface the [Python C API](http://docs.python.org/c-api/intro.html) directly.

For both you need the Python library, for Boost.Python approach you also need to link to the Boost.Python library.